# Convert black PNG icon to gray

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have some black icons in PNG (with transparency), and I want to turn them into a RGB(102, 102, 102) gray.

Here is one of my image :
[image]

I tried this command with imagemagick :

```
convert icon.png -fill "rgb(102,102,102)" -opaque black icon-gray.png
```

And this is the result : [image]

As you can see there is a uggly black border :/ Any help would be really appreciated, thank you !

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
convert icon.png +level-colors "rgb(102,102,102)", -transparent white result.png
```

Or maybe with some `fuzz`...

```
convert icon.png +level-colors "rgb(102,102,102)", -fuzz 5% -transparent white result.png
```

Or maybe this...

```
convert icon.png -fill "rgb(102,102,102)" +opaque white -transparent white result.png
```